# Vertical aligned text in a element with the table-cell display property in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having a hard time aligning some text inside a element styled with `display: table-cell`. It's just a tab, and I want it to support multiline text. To get the `vertical-align: middle;` right we need to display it as a table-cell and this is fine mostly, but not here.

On first load it looks like this in chrome. As you can see it's not really in the middle at all.
[image]

The very strange thing is, if you open up dev tools and change the `line-height` from `1` to `2` and then back to `1` it looks fine, like this:

[image]

Now if I change `line-height` to `0` and then back to `1` it looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it look good at page load? Is this a known issue?
It looks fine in Firefox, it seems to be chrome only issue.

Heres the CSS for the tab:

```
.tab-controller__item {
  display: inline-table;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  margin-right: 6px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #717171;
}
.tab-controller__item__link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 2em;
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 48px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
```

and the HTML is pretty basic:

```
<a class="tab-controller__item__link" href="#">
    <span class="icon-star"></span>Kampange<br>&amp; Bonus
</a>
```

Comment: What is the CSS for `tab-controller__item__link__icon icon-star`? Can you make a working example of the problem that we can see?

Comment: The icon is just a normal icon font. However I tried making a JSFiddle and then it just worked. Turns out that it's the custom font that messes up the rendering. If I change my font-family to `Arial` everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When using `display: table-cell`, you **must** have a parent container with `display: table` or `display: inline-table`.

In this case, it would be `inline-table` as your tabs are in a horizontal layout.

```
.tab {
    background-color: #F8AF46;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/t5pnLe33/

Comment: Thanks but I have done this. So this should not be the problem. Updated my CSS to show this as well.